Testing UI using Spring Boot clickable events which trigger JavaScript?
The Spring Boot project I am currently working on uses Selenium for testing UI. Is there a proper way to use Spring Boot's clickable events to trigger JavaScript functions which would perform some UI testing. Is it even a good practice to do testing this way?
I tried calling the JS functions inside the Thymeleaf and it worked. Not sure if there are better ways of doing this or if it is even a good practice.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
